# Updating a view from a command handler

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a file dialogue opening from the menu where a user can select a file. The FileDialog is called from the menu command's handler class in execute().

Based on the file the user selected, I would like to update a view, for which (I believe) I'd need the same Composite element that's passed to the view in createPartControl().

Is it possible to get access to it from the command handler, or would it be better to trigger the view updating via something like ISourceProviderListener or PropertyChangeListener?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
IViewPart part = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(executionEvent).getActivePage()
    .findView(viewId);
```

It would be better to first update the data that your view is displaying (the model in MVC) and the change in data should trigger view refresh. It's hard to say which listener is better without knowing all the details.